# Why does set().union(*list1) gives me the union of two list inside a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, argument-unpacking, set-union

I am doing an assignment, which requires me to do a code walkthrough. I would like to have a brief description on how set().union(*list1) works so i can answer during my walkthrough.

```
list1 = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3,5,8]]

x = set().union(*list1)

print(list(x))



#output = [1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.union

> union(*others)
>   set | other | ...
>   Return a new set with elements from the set and all others.

Also `*list` is called list unpacking, where we get the two sublists inside the list

```
In [37]: list1 = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3,5,8]]                                                                                         

In [38]: print(*list1)                                                                                                         
[1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
```

So the code you ran essentially creates a union of all the sublists within the list `x`, and since you know that the union of set `[1,2,3]` and `[1,2,3,5,8]` is `[1,2,3,5,8]`, hence the expected result.

Note that this is equivalent to `list(set([1,2,3]).union(set([1,2,3,5,8])))` where we are doing `a.union(b)`, `a` and `b` being sets

```
In [31]: list1 = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3,5,8]] 
    ...:  
    ...: x = set().union(*list1)                                                                                               

In [32]: print(list(x))                                                                                                        
[1, 2, 3, 5, 8]

In [33]: print(list(set([1,2,3]).union(set([1,2,3,5,8]))))                                                                     
[1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
```

Adding to this, a better approach to do `union` or even `intersection` might be to convert the list of lists to a list of sets, using `map(set,list1)`, unrolling the sets and then doing the operations

```
In [39]: list1 = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3,5,8]]                                                                                         

In [40]: print(set.intersection(*map(set,list1)))                                                                              
{1, 2, 3}

In [41]: print(set.union(*map(set,list1)))                                                                                     
{1, 2, 3, 5, 8}
```